# External api call using wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api, api, wp-api, plugin-json-api

I want to start a new website and chose wordpress as my cmd, but im having a restriction. The website is all about api request to other websites and i triedto get an api to test it as an example. After writing in php and add it to code snippet i got an error. I went through wordpress developers documentation and found out how to make an external api request, i did the same in the code snippet but still didn't work. So decided to code a php file and upload it into the wordpress directory, but before doing this, o decided to ask for help. About how to make and external api request from a wordpress website, where and how to input the code and use the api on a page or post?

This is the api i tried to use for test:
'''
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.apyhub.com/data/convert/currency' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--header 'apy-token: APT03xPn2ZVq7rFriUtRoamaY9Ucg1c7y17CPd60WtMW03' 
--data-raw '{
"source":"eur",
"target":"inr"
}'
'''

And i also tried using postman and it worked.

Please help.

Comment: If that `apy-token` is meant to be a private key, you should probably request a new one from the provider.

Comment: Regarding your question: WordPress provides a number of tools to allow you to collect data from remote sites. See, for example, [`wp_safe_remote_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_remote_post/) which allows you to send POST data to a remote URL and retrieve a response from it.

Comment: The problem here is that, im i yo add it to code snippet or where im i going to insert the code?

Comment: I'd recommend [writing a plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) for this. If you're not comfortable doing that, you might need to hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: Are you a developer that can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your curl request should work from the command line. Put you will want to use it in a PHP file:

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    $url = "https://api.com/";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

    // Receive server response ...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $api_output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

Which php file you put the curl in is going to be dependent on what you are trying to accomplish. For instance, you might setup [a cron job](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) to query the api once and hour, updating your content as necessary. Knowing what you are doing would allow me to provide more guidance.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean and why i need cron, but what im facing is how to execute the code from a wordpress website and receive a response from the front end.

Comment: @TaofeeqTajudeen What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the API call. It would help if you could clarify what you mean by "receive a response from the front end." What information are you intending to get and what will you be doing with it?

Comment: This api is just what i used for testing purpose, the API's i want to use is different. I want it to be used in front end to communicate between the two websites and also to my database

Comment: You could add simply add all this functionality in the page template. However, it would be better to create a plugin (or in your functions.php file) to update the database via cron and/or use AJAX to serve info from the API directly to users. Check out some resources on the subject. For instance, this example would not be exactly how I would do it, but you can get an idea: https://rapidapi.com/blog/integrate-external-api-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you so much, i will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [WPGetAPI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpgetapi/), a free plugin built just for this (if you want to go down the plugin route)